# "this" inside event handler from HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, this, handler

I thought I understood wel the "this" keyword until I saw this code :

```
<body>
    <button onclick="go()">clic1</button>

    <button id="btn">clic2</button>

    <script>

        function go() {
            console.log(this);
        }

        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        btn.onclick = function() {
            console.log(this)
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

I have a HTML document with two buttons that do the same thing when clicked :they log the "this" keyword.

I'm very surprised they don't show the same result :

For the button "clic1" : this = Window

For the button "clic2" : this = the button object with id "btn"

Is there any explanation for that ?

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Comment: Afaik, the first button's onclick is a function that does `eval("go()")` which causes `go` to lose the context and revert to `window` as context. It's one of the many reasons why inline code is bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### TLDR:

`go` is **not** the event handler of the first button. The event handler is an anonymous function generated by the HTML parser. In the example, the generated handler *just happens to call* `go`.

---

JavaScript code provided in HTML for an `onEventName` attribute is compiled into a function of form

```
function(event) {
    // code written in the attribute value
}
```

*Functions generated by the parser in this way have a rather strange scope chain which includes the element the generated handler is a property of, any outer **`form`** element the element is within, and the **`document`** object, at least. Reasons for the scope chain date back to before the DOM was standardized. Older IE releases provided `window.event` instead of the `event` parameter.*

So the first button

```
 <button onclick="go()">clic1</button>
```

in current browsers generates the button's onclick handler as:

```
 function( event) {
     go()
 }
```

- the onclick handler is the function taking the `event` parameter. It is called with a `this` value of the button.
- `go` is an ordinary function call - the `this` value of the caller has not been applied. You could, say, pass on `this` as a parameter by calling `go(this)` if you wanted to.
- `go` was declared using the `function` keyword and by default has a `this` value of the global object.
- If you must attach a [`myHandler`] function in HTML to be called *like* an event handler, add an attribute in the opening tag like

  ```html
  oneventname = "myHandler.call(this, event)"
  ```

  or *provided the `this` value is not required*, simply

  ```html
  oneventname="myHandler(event);
  ```

---

In the second example, you compile an anonymous function expression normally (not using the HTML parser) and attach it directly to the second button element.`

- the attached function is called with the button as its `this` value which can be logged to the console.
- the attached function does not have a wierdo scope chain.