# maxLength is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with an html page

here a simplified version of the page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function maxLength()
            {
                console.log('maxLength');
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type"text" onblur="maxLength()">
    </body>
</html>
```

on onblur event I receive this error

Uncaught TypeError: maxLength is not a function

but if i call the function from console it works without errors and print 'maxLength'

Why?

Comment: The code you posted works fine. Instead of the "simplified" version, perhaps you can post something closer to the *actual* version.

Comment: My guess is that there's a global variable, property, or function called maxLength. Try a different name for your function.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) in particular the `maxLength` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code there runs in the [context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744889/31671) of the `input`, which has defined `maxLength`.

Better developer tools would make it clearer:

> `maxLength` is not a function at `HTMLInputElement.onblur`

Rename your function to something else or use a different way of attaching the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the function to something else it should work fine for you. The explanation is aptly given with Alex already. Example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function maximumLength()
            {
                console.log('maxLength');
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type"text" onblur="maximumLength()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not a *keyword*, it's a property of `HTMLInputElement` which is being looked up because `onEvent` type attributes are weird for historical reasons and backwards compatibility.