# How to do an event listener so that = sign calculates Sum?

Tags: javascript

My understanding of an event handler is that it allows the event handler that takes an existing function and allows you to do something with it like a click or some kind of event

What I am trying to do is when the = button is pressed on my calculator it uses the calculation function and takes the if-else statements and applies it to the = sign. For example, if the user clicks 1 + 1 the = sign should add them together and give the answer.

```js
/*********************
Setting up varlaibles*
**********************/

let result;
let num1;
let num2;


/*****************************************
Function for numbers to display on screen*
******************************************/

function buttonPress(numbers) {

  let input = document.querySelector('.answer').innerText.split('\n').join('') + numbers
  let display = document.querySelector('.answer').innerHTML = input
  console.log(`${typeof display} ${display}`)

  if (display.length >= 21) {

    for (let i = 0; i < display.length; i++) {
      document.querySelector('.answer').style.marginTop = -i + "px";
    }
  }
}

/***********************************
Function for calculation of numbers*
************************************/

function calculation(buttonPress) {

  switch (numbers) {
    case "/":
      numbers / numbers;
      break;
    case "*":
      numbers * numbers;
      break;
    case "+":
      numbers + numbers;
      break;
    case "-":
      numbers - numbers;
      break;
    case "%":
      numbers % numbers;
      break;
    default:
  }

  buttonPress()
}
```

```html
<div class="answer"></div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-op clear" onclick="buttonPress('C')">C</button>
    <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('()')">()</button>
    <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('%')">%</button>
    <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('/')">/</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(1)">1</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(2)">2</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(3)">3</button>
    <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('X')">x</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(4)">4</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(5)">5</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(6)">6</button>
    <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('+')">+</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(7)">7</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(8)">8</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(9)">9</button>
    <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('-')">-</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num" id="border-left" onclick="buttonPress(0)">0</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress('.')">.</button>
    <button class="col-eq-end" id="border-right" onclick="buttonPress('=')">=</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

The outcome should be with addEventListener that if the user uses operators to with the numbers the = sign should give the answer.

Comment: Without criticism, the understanding expressed in the post reads as confused and using  a lot of hand-waving. "Event Handers" are function objects in JavaScript. The HTML parser compiles "oneventname" attribute values in an opening HTML tag into anonymous event handling functions, and adds them as event listeners to the HTML element created for the tag (as outlined in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744889/5217142) of mine). This information is _not included_ in [Introduction to events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) on MDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add listener

```
element.addEventListener('eventName', callbackFunction(){})
```

to calculate using simple method

```js
let result = eval("15 + 4 - 2 * 4")
console.log(result)
```

but they said `eval()` is evil so you can try method below

```js
let char, result = '';

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button=> {  // add click event to all button
  button.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    char = e.target.textContent;
    if (char == '=') {
      // using eval()
      // document.querySelector('.answer').textContent = eval(result)
      //
      let values = result.split(/([-+\/\*])/);
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (isNaN(values[i])) {
          let operator = values[i]
          i++;
          let nextNumber = parseFloat(values[i])
          result = operations[operator](result, nextNumber)
        } else {
          result = parseFloat(values[i])
        }
      }
    } else if (char == 'C') {
      result = '';
    } else {
      result += char;
    }
    document.querySelector('.answer').textContent = result
  })
})

var operations = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b,
};
```

```css
.answer{display: block;width: 200px;height: 20px;border: 1px solid #bbb;margin: 10px 0;}
```

```html
<div class="answer">0</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-op clear">C</button>
    <button class="col-op">()</button>
    <button class="col-op">%</button>
    <button class="col-op">/</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num">1</button>
    <button class="col-num">2</button>
    <button class="col-num">3</button>
    <button class="col-op-end">*</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num">4</button>
    <button class="col-num">5</button>
    <button class="col-num">6</button>
    <button class="col-op-end">+</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num">7</button>
    <button class="col-num">8</button>
    <button class="col-num">9</button>
    <button class="col-op-end">-</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num" id="border-left">0</button>
    <button class="col-num">.</button>
    <button class="col-eq-end" id="border-right">=</button>
  </div>

</div>
```