# How to stop working of a function with EventListner initiated by HTML attribute 'onclick' on a grid when Clicks on any cell of Grid created using div

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I am doing Etch a sketch project with JavaScript and DOM methods.
This is what I did

1. created a grid.
2. **`ChangeColour()` function called using onclick** attribute.( Function includes EventListener( Event: mouseover) to give background colour for each cells.)

**I want to stop Coloring cells when clicks on any Cell**.

I tried return; and removeEventListner() function. Both didn't work.

HTML:

```
<section id="container"></section>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
let i = 0;
container.innerHTML =
                    `<section class="row">${'<div class="cell" onclick="changeColour()"></div>'.repeat(n)}</section>`
                         .repeat(n)

function changeColour(){

               const cells = document.querySelectorAll('div');
cells.forEach((div) => {
                    div.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                         div.setAttribute('style', 'background: black;');
                    })
               })
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove the event handler created from the `onclick` attribute because you don't have a reference to it - it was [created by the HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744889/5217142).

If you add the event listener in JavaScript instead of HTML, using `changeColor` as the handler, you should be able to remove it easily. I'm not sure this is exactly what you want to achieve, but along the lines of:

```js
"use strict";
const n=3; // testing

container.innerHTML =
    `<section class="row">${'<div class="cell"></div>'.repeat(n)}</section>`
    .repeat(n)

const changeColor = event => {event.currentTarget.style.background="black"}
const clickHandler = event => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach( cell=> {
    cell.removeEventListener( "click", clickHandler);
    cell.removeEventListener("mouseover", changeColor);
  });
}


document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(div=> {
     div.addEventListener("click",clickHandler);
     div.addEventListener("mouseover", changeColor);
});
```

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin solid blue;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<!-- body-html -->
<section id="container"></section>
```

Comment: Is there another way? When I do another action(like double click), I want to stop 'mouseover' Event Listener (or) stop the entire function.

Comment: Please read the answer completed as intended (I hit the enter key by accident and posted it early). What ever you do you need to retain a reference to event handler functions in order to remove them using `removeEventListener`.  Removing them by setting HTML element `oneventname` attributes to null is so HTML 3 that I don't want to even consider going there.