# How to add onmouseover styling to an element through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Attempting to remove and reapply function to the onmouseover event of an element. Not sure how to go about this, have attempted several ways without any luck.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="my_button" onmouseover="myFunction(this)">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction(ele) {
  alert("hi")
  document.getElementById("my_button").onmouseover = "null";
  document.getElementById("my_button").onmouseover = "myFunction(this)";
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting the button `onmouseover` property to a string in `myFunction` instead of to a function object.

The HTML parser creates an anonynmous handler function from the `onmousever` attribute value for you, but setting the button property to a string in JavaScript won't create such a function. Try

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="my_button" onmouseover="myFunction.call(this, event)">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction(event) {
  alert("hi, this.tagName = " + this.tagName)
  document.getElementById("my_button").onmouseover = "null";
  document.getElementById("my_button").onmouseover = myFunction; // a function object
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice I've modified `myFunction` to see the button object as its `this` value, and its argument to be the mouse event raised for the click, and changed the call in the handler generated by the HTML to call `myFunction` as if it were the actual event handler. This was to keep the calls to `myFunction` seeing the button as its `this` value and `event` as its argument in both cases.

For more about the handler created by the HTML parser see a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744889/5217142)   (disclaimer: of mine) to *'`this` inside event handler from HTML attribute'* that goes into greater detail.

---

Note that for various reasons it is no longer recommended to create event handlers using `oneventname` attribute values in HTML when you can add them using `element.addEventListener` in JavaSript as part of initialization.

Comment: Thank you, works perfect! Just started Javascript, have been calling functions like this in html, onmouseover= "myFunction(this)"; I assumed this was the only way to pass it, appreciate the detail.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
<button id="my_button" onmouseover="alert('hi')">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Im referring to applying a function I premade in a javascript file. document.getElementById("my_button").onmouseover = "myFunction(this)";

Answer (score 0):

try

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="my_button" class="mousemove" >try it</button>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("mousemove")[0].onmousemove = function(){
  alert("hi")
  document.getElementById("my_button").onmousemove = function(){ return null }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```